DropdownButton2 flutter onTap
I'm trying to navigate (scroll) to the end of the page when I tap on my "DropdownButton2" to show all my items  using:

scrollController.animateTo(
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 40),
       curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);

The problem is that the "DropdownButton2" has no "onTapped" property, and wrapping it in "InkWell" or "GestureDetector" doesn't respond to tapping but responds to other actions like long pressing.
Can someone help?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also format your code properly using the post editor.

You can use TapRegion to detect tap event without participating gesture disambiguation.

thanks @PurplePolyhedron that works! If you can answer it with explanation ill green flag it.


Suggest wrapping the DropdownButton2 with a widget like GestureDetector or InkWell to detect taps. Explain that this will allow capturing the tap action, which can trigger the scrolling logic before or after interacting with the dropdown.

Recommend ensuring that the scroll controller logic is working correctly and tied to the scrollable widget (like a ListView or SingleChildScrollView).

Point out that the GestureDetector or InkWell needs to be carefully placed around the DropdownButton2 so that it doesn't interfere with the dropdown functionality.

Emphasize testing to make sure the dropdown opens properly while also handling the scroll action.



Hi, first thanks for the response.Second as I said wrapping a DropdownButton with an InkWell or GestureDetecor dosent listen to taps as discussed also here :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52671

Using TapRegion() solves the issue.
